# Understanding Java Inheritance and function creation

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I have a base class which goes as below

```
class BaseClass{
  //this is a base class
  // I dont want to add any generic methods here as it is 
  //extended by tens of classes
}
```

Now Two particular classes which extends this base class

```
class Abc extends BaseClass{

//method
  void letsGo(){
    //this method is not there in base class
  }
}
```

```
class Xyz extends BaseClass{

//method
void letsGo(){
    //this method is not there in base class
  }

}
```

Now I need a function which have to accepts Class Xyz's object or Class Abc's object with a syntax similar to below

```
void run (BaseClass base){
  base.letsGo() // I know it wont work 
}
```

and call it like `run(object of Abc)` or `run(object of Xyz)` .

How do I implement this. I dont want to add abstract method in base class as it is extended by many classes

Comment: " I dont want to add abstract method in base class as it is extended my classes" .. what do you mean by that? It is unclear to me.

Comment: There's many ways to do this, depending on your actual use case and needs. One possible solution is to add a common parent only for these two classes with the abstract method.

Comment: A real-world example might help us understand your situation better.

Comment: If you haven't declared `letsGo()` as a method of `baseClass`, it doesn't make sense to want to call `base.letsGo()`. Why don't you want to declare an abstract method?

Comment: An Abstract Class can have both abstract and Concrete methods. 
In your case I would create a simple interface with letsGo() method and implement that interface to the classes Abc and Xyz. You can extend only one class but you can implement as many Interfaces as you want.

Comment: You do understand that this is exactly a use case where you could have an abstract method that the extending classes need to implement. There is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that the parent class `BaseClass` will be inherited by many children, but only a small subset of the children will need to implement `letsGo`. I think the easiest solution is to make an intermediate subclass, say `MediumClass`(extending `BaseClass`) that contains the method `letsGo` and then make `Abc` and `Xyz` inherit that. Finally, make the `run` method take the intermediate class as the argument.